# Meaning of the word "even" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/T_4JBbeGsSE). It is at 9 minute and 18 second.

> It is a great opportunity to get ideas for your resume, or help you figure out if it is **even** a job you want.

I can understand what the adverb **even** means, but I am confused what it means there. Was it used as a synonym if the phrase *at all*? For example:

> It is a great opportunity to get ideas for your resume, or help you figure out if you want this job **at all**.

Do those two sentences mean the same?

Comment: In this particular context it means *indeed*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sentence, **even** is used more for emphasis, therefore without a special meaning in itself.

While "**at all**" in your example is acceptable, it departs a little from the original meaning.

As a "replacement", the word "**really**" fits better (although still not meaning exactly the same thing as "**even**"):

> ... or help you figure out if it is **really** a job you want.